# Is it okay to mention future end date of internship on CV/Resume?

Tags: resume, job-search, work-experience

I am doing a 6-month internship at a company. The duration of the internship is from April 2017 to September 2017. Right now, I will be applying for student jobs that I will start from October 2017.

How should I mention the duration of the current internship on my CV/Resume? Is it okay if I mention the future end date like this?

> Apr 2017 - Sep 2017

Or should I use:

> Apr 2017 - Present

...and then mention the actual end date on my cover letter?

---

Just to clear any confusion, there is no possibility either for an extension of the internship's duration nor for a full-time job offer at the company. The company only employs Masters degree holders for its engineering positions. Right now, I still have my thesis left that I have to do after returning back to university. So, an immediate extension of the internship contract or full-time employment is out of the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Writting down the end date helps to convey two messages:

- I will be available by October
- I will not be leaving another job for this one (as in "I am not prone to leave my current job for other offers, and that will include your job").

In order to avoid confusing/missleading the reviewer of your CV, you could write something like:

> - Internship at X: April 2017 - Setember 2017 (end of internship contract)

That said, my answer is only that "it is ok to write the end date", but I would not find it wrong if you would just leave it empty. It is not a very important detail.

Answer (score 1):

**The answer is, it is a personal preference between two totally common and widely accepted options:
1) Apr 2017 - Sep 2017 (If you're going to abbreviate the months, don't forget the periods. For example, Apr. )
2) To be completed Sep 2017
That's it. Done and done.**

Here is why (in case you're interested):
Most (if not all) companies realize the very definition of an internship includes a set time period. (Yes, there is a different type of internship where there isn't a defined end date, but that's the lesser known type. Most companies hear "internship" and will ask, "when does it end.") Most internships are a pre-determined time period (usually 3 or 6 months).

This question reminds me of folks who are in the middle taking classes that they mention on their resume but haven't finished the course yet. Same idea applies.

It also reminds me of resumes of people (like me) who do contract work. Although contract jobs are offered by staffing agencies/temp companies, the reason it's called a "contract" or a "short-term" position specifically, is because there is a start date and an end date. Not all temp jobs are short. People can work as temps for years at the same "assignment".

Job ads that read, "Contract position available for an Administrative Assistant, 6 months, for our client (they usually don't tell you the clients name until you call about the job) in any-town, any-state for $23/hr. If interested, please call XYZ Temp Company.

Many times a position will be listed and it's only until you email or call to apply that they tell you the details and that it is, in fact, a short-term assignment for XYZ company and the rate per hour you will receive.

Hope that helps!